# How can I block by location in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, blocking

Still new and learning how to use R, but I'd like to get some help with figuring out how to block my data by location. I found [this tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/analysis-variance/randomized-block-design), but I don't understand where to put my data into the code.

I have 14 locations, 2 treatments (yes/no), and count data of the number of calls per species. My data looks basically like this:

```
location treatment species1  
BC       yes        20   
BC       no         11  
BC       yes       880   
DW       no          3  
DW       yes       230  
DW       yes         0  
YZ       yes       390   
YZ       no          0  
YZ       yes       540  
(etc...)
```

(only in a .csv file)

Because it's count data I'm trying to use `glm`, and `family=poisson` (or `quasipoisson`) so my basic formula without the blocked locations looks like this:

```
sp1calls = glm(species1~treatment, family=poisson)
```

and I know that the number of treatment levels is 2, and the number of control blocks is 14, but in the website's directions I don't understand how to get my data into the code they give.

Rephrased: I get `k=2` and `n=14`, but does `f=c("yes", "no")`?  What is the `1` for? Why is the function `gl`?  Since it's an example for randomized block design in ANOVA, is `glm` different?

Once I have `blk=(something)`, the final code should be:

```
sp1callswithblock = glm(sp1~treatment+block, family=poisson)
```

right? (or something like that?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if maybe you prefer a mixed effects model, but in ANOVA a 'blocking factor' is just a nuisance categorical variable that is loaded up with whatever features you want to control for and on which you think some observations will cluster.  There isn't really anything very special about this.  In your case, make sure your `location` is a factor, and then include it in the model.

```
mydataframe$location = as.factor(mydataframe$location)
sp1calls = glm(species1~location+treatment, family=poisson)
```

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was from misusing terms.  By saying "block" what I meant was "nested" and I found the solution [here](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/LMM_Examples.R).

So, my code is now:

```
lmersp1loc=lmer(sp1~treatment + (1|location/treatment), data = mydataframe)
```

I had to load the package lme4, but everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Since your response variable is a count, you presumably want to use `glmer(..., family=poisson)`.

Comment: @gung: you're right, I did use glmer